# print a page with out print url of page?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using `window.print()` to print a page. It is also printing the url of the page. How can I avoid this (using code)?

Answer (score 4):

This is a user preference which is not possible to override from a webpage. The user has to change their preferences manually.

Update in response to editing of tags: And as something that changes the behavior of the client, if this *was* possible, then it wouldn't be achievable using asp.net or any other server side technology.

Comment: i use this code it's working in IE but is not wworking in FireFox

Comment: <a href="#"  onclick="window.print()" onmouseup="document.getElementById('header').style.display='None';document.getElementById('footer').style.display='None'"> Print </a>